# How can I publish one document from the collection to the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

When I try to use `find()` as the following:

```
Meteor.publish('currentRequest', function (requestId) {
    console.log(requestId)
    console.log( Requests.find( {_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(requestId)} ).fetch() ); // The item is printed successfully to the terminal
    return Requests.find( {_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(requestId)} ).fetch();
});
```

Here is how I subscribe in the client:

```
Template.requestView.onCreated(function () {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe('currentRequest', Session.get('requestId'));
    });
});
```

Ane here is my helper:

```
Template.requestView.helpers({
    currentRequest: function() {
        console.log(Requests.findOne(new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(Session.get('requestId'))) );   
        return Requests.find( {_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(requestId)} ).fetch();
    }
});
```

But I get the following error:

> Exception from sub currentRequest id m9X5fgYNNtLN6JAXt Error: Publish
>   function returned an array of non-Cursors

When I try to change all the code above from `find()` to `findOne()` as below

```
Requests.findOne(new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(requestId));
```

I get the following error:

> Exception from sub currentRequest id vqjwt7sggLESxeNtc Error: Publish
>   function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors

Comment: The error messages you're getting contain the solution to your problem. `Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors` - `.fetch()` returns an *array* and `.findOne()` returns an *object*. Neither of these are *cursors*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `fetch()`.

This transforms the cursor from `find()` into an array, which `Meteor.Publish` does not like and complains about in your error message.